# AnkhSVN not showing in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, ankhsvn

I cannot see AnkhSVN as an option under "Tools - Options - Source Control" in Visual Studio 2017.  I have uninstalled and reinstalled AnkhSVN, but no effect.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Did you install this version https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-303797.AnkhSVN-SubversionSupportforVisualStudio?

Comment: @KenTucker - I installed it using Tools | Extensions and Updates, which gave me version 2.7.12815 (which is the latest version quoted on the page you referenced).

Comment: I tried everything mentioned in the answers but no avail.  We freshly installed windows 10 professional with the latest and greatest updates including the Fall Update on my system few weeks back.  The latest Visual Studio 2017 build doesn't detect AnkhSVN at all.  There is nothing in the options/toolbar but there is an entry "AnkSVN 2.6.12735.14 in the add/remove program.

Comment: Other tools also have the same issue as well.  I don't see this problem in non Windows 10 professional with the fall update.  I almost want to conclude the fall update is a major cluster &*(&#$%()#.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I came here looking for an answer to the same question.  I am Running Windows 10 Enterprise and had VS2015 with AnkhSVN working before and after installing VS2017, but in VS2017 AnkhSVN was not available under SCC Plug-In Selection (even after uninstall and reinstall of the install executables downloaded from http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net, which offer registration against VS Dev15/2017).

This is what eventually worked:

1. Removed AnkhSVN (Windows: Add or Remove Programs)
2. Installed AnkhSVN Nuget package (Visual Studio: Tools/Extensions and Updates)

So the trick I believe is to "remove program installed by MSI/EXE followed by install extension via Visual Studio VSIX".

I was also subsequently able to upgrade AnkhSVN (2.7.12815 from VSIX install), by running the downloaded EXE installer for the latest daily build (2.7.12821), after which AnkhSVN is available in both VS2015 and 2017, although I had to reselect it in 2015.

Comment: Yes, downloading the VSIX and installing it from that fixed it.  I'd previously installed it from inside VS.  Weird one!  Thanks :)

Comment: VS2017 no longer supports the registry based install that was used for VS2005-2015. Only some very early preview versions supported this. We will have to use the vsix install for future versions.

Comment: For VS 2017 this worked but I have community edition VS 2015 and it is still not working for that

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue with VS2017 and tried the solution provided by AlanK to no avail.
Here is the solution that solved the problem for me:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/119486/on-fresh-installation-extensions-are-not-working.html

> 1. Uninstall the source control plug-in.
> 2. Make a backup of the following files:
>
>    - C:\USERS\USERNAME\APPDATA\LOCAL\MICROSOFT\VISUALSTUDIO\15.0_XXXXXXXX\privateregistry.bin
>    - C:\USERS\USERNAME\APPDATA\LOCAL\MICROSOFT\VISUALSTUDIO\15.0_XXXXXXXX\privateregistry.user.bin
> 3. Remove these files:
>
>    - C:\USERS\USERNAME\APPDATA\LOCAL\MICROSOFT\VISUALSTUDIO\15.0_XXXXXXXX\privateregistry.bin
>    - C:\USERS\USERNAME\APPDATA\LOCAL\MICROSOFT\VISUALSTUDIO\15.0_XXXXXXXX\privateregistry.user.bin
> 4. Start Visual Studio 2017.
> 5. Install the source control plug-in.

Comment: Please copy here concerned content, links can be changed or removed

Comment: Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1):

You have to install "Ankh.VS15Package.vsix" package along with AnkhSVN software in your system as the version of AnkhSVN that you are installing might be supporting only up to Visual Studio 2015 or less. I had the same issue and resolved it by installing the package mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue after one of the Visual Studio 2017 updates. I had Visual Studio running and I was attempting to follow @AlanK's steps. I uninstalled as in Step 1. When I did Step 2, VS said the plugin was installed already. I restarted Visual Studio, thinking it was confused about the fact I uninstalled via Add/Remove programs.

I checked again and the AnkhSVN plugin was shown as disabled. I enabled it and then AnkhSVN and VS 2017 started playing nicely again.

I read the answer from Snehlata Shaw, and I think what I uninstalled from Add/Remove programs is the 2015 and earlier version of AnkhSvn. I can't be 100% sure that uninstalling it did or did not help with the 2017 version.

In summary, make sure the plugin isn't just disabled. VS 2017 says (now that is enabled) that AnknSvn slows down startup by 6 seconds and perhaps I disabled it not realizing what I was doing (Monday morning??).